# Как программно закрыть Android-приложение?

Tags: android, java

`System.exit(0);` не работает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не надо его принудительно закрывать. Система сама его закроет. Читай доки:
[What is Android?](http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html)

Comment: Я хочу сделать кнопку "Exit". Такая есть во многих приложениях.

Comment: На самом деле такая кнопка не нужна...при нажатии на back рано или поздно приложение закроется. С другой стороны все зависит от интерфейса приложения и потребностей.

Comment: На самом деле надо проектировать приложение правильно. Система сама контролирует закрытие приложения.

Answer (score 5):

Можно воспользоваться методом активити finish(), при условии, что это последнее активити в стеке приложение закроется, а можно убить процесс полностью независимо от количества активити в нем. Есть и такие методы.

Answer (score 4):

`android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`

Comment: Я попробовал так. У меня приложение сначала закрывается, а потом как-то само перезапускается снова. Из-за чего это?

Comment: очень странно. по идеи, процесс убивается полностью и вычищается из памяти.

Comment: Может быть, надо какие-то permissions дописать в манифест.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `finishAffinity()`.

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```java
public void OnClick_TEST (View view) {
        // Завершить работу данного окна
        this.finish();
    }
```