# Уничтожение Android приложения из него самого или из его сервиса

Tags: android, delphi, radstudio, firemonkey

Мне необходимо, когда пользователь нажимает кнопку «Закрыть», уничтожить приложение. Если указать Action = caFree, приложение остается висеть в памяти, не уничтожается, методы Destroy в приложении и сервисе не срабатывают:

```
procedure TfmMain.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  DM.LocationSensor.Active := false;
  Action := TCloseAction.caFree;
end;
```

Если уничтожить приложение в смартфоне через «Последние приложения», тогда приложение уничтожается, сервис приложения перезапускается, и продолжает работать — это мне и надо.

Помогите пожалуйста понять, как же правильно уничтожить приложение при закрытии основной формы?

Подойдут решения отправки Intent, куда нужно, или вызовы нативных Android методов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. В PlatformSDK находим класс android\os\Process.java
2. Компилируем его в Process.class
3. Упаковываем в JAR
4. Конвертируем JAR в DEX
5. Объединяем с Classes.dex
6. С помощью Java2OP.exe делаем обертку для Delphi — Androidapi.JNI.Os.Process.pas
7. Импортируем в проект полученную библиотеку

Вызываем код:

```
TJProcess.JavaClass.killProcess(TJProcess.JavaClass.myPid);
```

Все это можно было заменить вызовом кода

```
var
  LJO: JObject;
begin
  TJActivityManager.Wrap((LJO as ILocalObject).GetObjectID).killBackgroundProcesses(TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageName);
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Как написано [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/67974/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-android-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5):

Можно воспользоваться методом активити finish(), при условии, что это последнее активити в стеке приложение закроется, а можно убить процесс полностью независимо от количества активити в нем.

Или же воспользоваться этим:
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Comment: Воспользоваться штатно в FireMonkey методом killProcess нет возможности, но идея понятна.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте

```
ANativeActivity_finish(System.DelphiActivity);
```

И не забудьте подключить `Androidapi.NativeActivity`